# Invoking a Continuously Running Webjob via Kudu API

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, kudu

Is it possible to invoke a function on a continuously-running Webjob via the Kudu Webjob API?

I have looked at the documentation @ https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#invoke-a-triggered-job but unable to see anything regarding invoking a function on a continuously running webjob.

I am hoping to find/use something like:

```
POST /api/continuouswebjobs/{job name}/run?arguments={arguments}
```

**EDIT**
FYI - I am able to invoke the function manually via the Kudu dashboard, as below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as 'invoking' a continuous WebJob. By nature, a continuous WebJob is something that starts and runs forever. The only actions you can take on it is to start and stop it.

By contrast, triggered WebJobs are designed to be specifically invoked.

Comment: I am talking about invoking a function on a continuous webjob - see the above screenshot for what I am talking about

Comment: The key here is to not confuse WebJobs with WebJobs **SDK**. Kudu only knows about WebJobs, and from its point of view, it's just a random exe. The fact that your exe uses the WebJobs SDK end has WebJobs SDK 'functions' is completely opaque to Kudu (hence it can't possibly have an API to call them). The dashboard UI you show, OTOH, does know about WebJobs SDK functions. But it does not have a documented API.

Comment: @Thomas not sure I follow?

Comment: Not sure either. I didn't think @Nagoh was in any way aggressive.

Comment: @Nagoh, sorry for that, I felt you were a little bit aggressive, I ll remove my comment